# Asp.net 4.6 Angular 2 Webpack

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, webpack

I have existing ng2 asp.net 4.6 project. Right now I am using systemjs,but I want to migrate to the webpack (that is new hot thing, isn't?:) )

I can't find asp.net 4.6 guide for webpack..or any asp.net project where I could find the correct setup.

Do you know any guides or github projects where I could learn about webpack setup in asp.net 4.6 environment?

I found webpack + asp.net 4.6 tutorial http://developer.telerik.com/featured/webpack-for-visual-studio-developers/

but it doesn't cover ng2 setup
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Steve Sanderson's blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/05/02/angular2-react-knockout-apps-on-aspnet-core/) and the corresponding [ASP.NET Core JavaScriptServices](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices) middleware.

Comment: I am looking for something specific with ASP.NET 4.6

Comment: There is no difference what are you using on server side. Idea stays the same. I migrated from systemjs to webpack by using this cook book and everything went very smooth. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html

Comment: that what I am trying to use right now, but keep getting random errors for each step I take. I understand what every setup is different. Perhaps, I am just trying to find a shortcut and just have a look at out-of-the-box asp.net project :)

Comment: Just scroll down, and implement everything what is needed for prod. and dev. environment (dont do step by step implementation). The only thing which i couldn't solve is awesome-typescript-compiler random errors regarding on typings, so i am using ts-loader instead.

Comment: @Brivvirs, if it helps, here's an [example implementation](https://github.com/JaimeStill/Core-Platform-Demo/blob/master/webpack.config.js) of using `awesome-typescript-compiler` in webpack config. See the `sharedConfig` object. This is from [my latest project](https://github.com/JaimeStill/Core-Platform-Demo) that uses Angular2, ASP.NET Core, and Semantic UI. See it [live in Azure](http://core-angular-platform.azurewebsites.net/).

Comment: please addd a link for asp mvc 4.x this is the best I've found: https://developer.telerik.com/featured/webpack-for-visual-studio-developers/